# Integer Array Handling

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I have a 2D game that uses two integer arrays to track x and y coordinates as shown below:

```
private int gridX[] = { 0,0,0,0,0 }
private int gridY[] = { 0,0,0,0,0 }
```

The problem is I can have a LOT of objects on the screen that needs to be tracked. Is there a way to add integers / create new blocks as needed? IE in a loop, do something like 
gridX[].add(); or something like that. I'm relatively new to java and droid development and I'm having trouble finding a good tutorial or example that shows how to do this without having to initialize the gridX and gridY to sizes of 100 or so.

This is important, as I am about 90% sure that all those unused 0's are causing androids garbage cleanup to lag my application.

Comment: In Java a plain array cannot change its size once its been created. ArrayList is probably what your looking for as @MBU said.

Comment: It would be wise to store corresponding x and y coordinates in the same object so that they are linked together and harder to confuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not also use the [Point](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Point.html) class?

```
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();

points.add(new Point(0, 0));
points.add(new Point(50, 70));

Point point = points.get(1);
Log.d("MyApp", String.format("The point is: (%d, %d)", point.x, point.y);
```

This way you are keeping track of your x and y coordinates together and there is less opportunity for error.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like the best solution. Do you know if using this method if I can specify the index? Like points.add(INDEX, values); ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. However, keep in mind that inserting doesn't perform very well (in general, the later elements have to be "moved over" to make room)

Comment: Awesome, was looking at keeping a specific object the number 0 object no matter what, but the obvious simple solution there is to just create it first. Thanks a lot for your help, I'm pretty sure this will drastically increase performance.

Comment: Actually `int[]` will always have better performance than `ArrayList<Integer>` or `ArrayList<Point>` unless you are copying and moving around sections of your array. The bonus of the methods in the answers here is that they make your life easier as a programmer, and the performance difference is not big enough to justify the headache of using `int[]`.

Comment: The actual performance of the application is fine. I probably stated that wrong. But I'm working on a hunch, as I haven't been in Java / Droid development long enough to know for sure. The GC is being called every 5 seconds on my app and I am pretty sure it is because I have a grid that is preset with over 100 0's. So I am pretty sure the GC is trying to clean it up and causing latency.

Comment: Just to follow up on this, using POINT actually created a big problem that I now have to go back and undo. POINT requires integers and my 2D game makes calculated movements so when the numbers are changing slightly, the direction is inconsistent. Additionally, it actually causes latency using point because updating the point locations requires me to create a new point object and essentially causing more garbage cleanup to occur. Finally, I haven't completely figured out this one yet, but if I reference a Point object to the Point arraylist, it has unusual effects.

Comment: You can change point.x and point.y without creating a new object. These are public fields.

Comment: Also note that for floats there is `PointF`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html

Comment: Example: Point blah = grid.get(0); blah.x+=5; Crazy things happen when I try to do this. Has that created a reference that automatically updates grid when I modify blah? Very unusual numbers are coming as a result of that especially if I reuse that blah down the line on a different index in the grid arrayList.

Comment: Yes, you need to use a different (new) point object for each index in the list, or else the slots in the list are actually pointing to the same point object and will each reflect an update in that object.

Comment: Thanks so much. Saved me so much time. Switched it to PointF and it took off right away. So many conversion issues was making the game do crazy stuff. Sorry if I'm not very informed on all this stuff. :D I have strengths in mostly online programming and design and wanted to get back into this area.

Comment: I didn't know about Point or PointF before this question, so it was certainly an educational experience for me as well!

Comment: Nice, lol. Well this program is litterally my Android "hello world" program right now, lol... Anyway... The final (?) summary here is that using this method did dramatically reduce the Garbage Collection. I still get it occasionally, and I will clean that up in more detail when the application is finished. (I have preset variables that I am not using yet.) Thanks again Matthew. I was gonna try sending you a message, but you don't list an email anywhere and I don't know if stackoverflow has a messaging system... Heh.

Comment: I added some contact details to my user profile. Hopefully they aren't too cryptic. I was trying to avoid spam!

Answer (score 5):

Why dont you use an array list instead of an Integer array?
that way you can dynamically add items to the list

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList  = new ArrayList<Integer>();

myList.add(1);
myList.add(2);
```

Comment: Agreed. It can be very annoying to change the size of an array dynamically. It can be done, but it usually isn't pretty.